# Are we finding the density of $x$ or evaluating the density of $\theta$ at $x$? | Alpyadin Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, parameter-estimation

In section $4.4$ The Bayes Estimator of Alpaydin he discusses the use of the prior density of $p(\theta)$ to construct a posterior density for $\theta$. This is standard Bayesian estimation to get a parameter density.

He then goes on to say

For estimating the density at $\chi$, we have

$\begin{align}
p(\chi | X) &= \int p(\chi, \theta | X) d\theta \\
&= \int p(\chi | \theta, X) p(\theta | X) d\theta \\
&= \int p(\chi | \theta) p(\theta | X) d\theta
\end{align}$

At this point is he still talking about the posterior density of the parameter evaluated at a given $\chi$ or is he talking about the actual density of our data $p(\chi)$?

Comment: Welcome. Posting image is discouraged. [Images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13677/963109) may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. Since you are new contributor, the images have been converted to text for once (If you can't see text, assume that conversion process is in Queue). It is advisable to get yourself trained with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/963109) so that from future you can type your question self. Happy Learning!